# Unable to start service rekab.app.background_locator.IsolateHolderService

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use background_locator to track geo_location when the user activates tracking by clicking a button. The location is then posted to an API, which logs it in a database.

The feature works in debug mode, but crashes with the following exception, in release mode:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31736): Process: za.co.liquidedge.celltrack, PID: 31736
E/AndroidRuntime(31736): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service rekab.app.background_locator.IsolateHolderServiceolateHolderService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4759)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2186)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)6)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)           a:8506)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)                                                                              aller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsC.java:1130)aller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)                                                      r.
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInite:26).java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parametece:0)r.                                                                                   )
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at d.c.c.O.a.getSuperclassTypeParameter(Unknown Sourc23)e:26)                                                                                onStartCommand(:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at d.c.c.O.a.<init>(Unknown Source:7)                ityThread.java:4741)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at rekab.app.background_locator.e.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at rekab.app.background_locator.f.b(Unknown Source:24)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at rekab.app.background_locator.g.d.a(Unknown Source:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at rekab.app.background_locator.IsolateHolderService.onStartCommand(:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(31736):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4741)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding these rules to `android/app/proguard-rules.pro`

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```